# maven build fails with special characters in filenames

Tags: maven, special-characters, filenames

In my maven project files with special characters in the name.
ex: *xyz, abc.zip* | *xyz' abc.zip* . Character encoding is set as UTF-8

When I build my bundle, I get the below error:

```
[ERROR] Bundle com.parent:com.mybundle:bundle:1.45.0-SNAPSHOT : Input file does not exist: data/ip/xyz
[ERROR] Bundle com.parent:com.mybundle:bundle:1.45.0-SNAPSHOT : Input file does not exist: src/main/resources/data/ip/xyz
[ERROR] Bundle com.parent:com.mybundle:bundle:1.45.0-SNAPSHOT : Input file does not exist: abc.zip**
```

Comment: Do you have the file names correctly set in your build ? Why you have special chars in the files which are used in the build :O You can always add extract pre-build script which renames your files.

Comment: First: Why do you need such file names?

Comment: The files are the resources that are used as payload for the REST calls in my test scripts.

Comment: Than the settings of your files (environment / OS) is not correct related to your filenames...Can you show the pom file?